# How to get recent value from the textbox on keyup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code will alert full value from the textbox formula. Is there any way to get exactly recent value from the text box on jquery keyup event.

```
$("#formula").keyup(function(){
    if($.isNumeric($(this).val()))

        alert(($(this).val()))

    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the provided event.

```
$("#formula").keyup(function(e){
    alert(String.fromCharCode(e.which))
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jOoOhfGxjJ9hERFTpa2Q?p=preview

or as Amir and Rajesh suggested

```
$("#formula").keypress(function(e){
    alert(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which))
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nP5UTF2rUivDDzhvimU7?p=preview

Comment: it is better to use `keypress` event if you want to get the real character.

Comment: I would also suggest to use `keyCode` as a fail-safe. `var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;`

Answer (score 3):

You Should use keypress event

```
$("#formula").keypress(function(event){ 
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.which))
});
```

On `keyup` event you can not detect `uppercase` or `lowercase` character and there are problems when user press `SHIFT`, `ALT` or some other keys like them. So it is recommended to use `keypress` event to get actual input.
For more you can visit here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keypress.asp and
https://api.jquery.com/keypress/